# boost::regex with case-insensitive match with UTF-8 (e.g. uppercase versus lowercase umlauts)

Tags: c++, regex, boost, utf-8

After building boost::regex version 1.52 libraries with International Components for Unicode (ICU) support, a regular expression with a case-insensitive match doesn't appear to handle uppercase and lowercase German umlaut characters as expected.

```
static const std::string pattern("^.*" "\303\226" ".*$");
static const std::string   test1("SCH" "\303\226" "NE");
static const std::string   test2("sch" "\303\266" "ne");
static const boost::regex exp(pattern, boost::regex::icase);
const char *result = (boost::regex_match(test1, exp)) ? "Match" : "NoMatch";
std::cout << "Testing \"" << test1 << "\" against pattern \"" << pattern 
    << "\" : " << result << std::endl;
result = (boost::regex_match(test2, exp)) ? "Match" : "NoMatch";
std::cout << "Testing \"" << test2 << "\" against pattern \"" << pattern 
    << "\" : " << result << std::endl;
```

Yields:

```
Testing "SCHÖNE" against pattern "^.*Ö.*$" : Match
Testing "schöne" against pattern "^.*Ö.*$" : NoMatch
```

Answer (score 2):

[Working with Unicode and ICU string types](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu.html).

[Example on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/308asr%240).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/regex/icu.hpp>
int main()
{
   static const std::string pattern("^.*" "\303\226" ".*$");
   static const std::string   test1("SCH" "\303\226" "NE");
   static const std::string   test2("sch" "\303\266" "ne");
   static const boost::u32regex exp=boost::make_u32regex(pattern, boost::regex::icase);
   const char *result = (boost::u32regex_match(test1, exp)) ? "Match" : "NoMatch";
   std::cout << "Testing \"" << test1 << "\" against pattern \"" << pattern 
      << "\" : " << result << std::endl;
   result = (boost::u32regex_match(test2, exp)) ? "Match" : "NoMatch";
   std::cout << "Testing \"" << test2 << "\" against pattern \"" << pattern 
      << "\" : " << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate it.  One minor issue is that my environment can't seem to compile your solution.  I get multiple undefined references in "u_tolower_49", but I'll work on it.  Many thanks.